# Framebuffer Incomplete Attachment for Texture with Internal Format?

Tags: opengl

So i am trying to create a FrameBuffer where i render to a texture, but i can't seem to get it to work with the format i need. That is GL_RGB32F. It works for GL_RGB16F and GL_RGBA32F so i don't understand why GL_RGB32F is giving me GL_FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMEPLETE_ATTACHMENT from glCheckFramebufferStatus. I get no errors from the calls creating the texture either. Is there a special requirement to use that internal format? Can i see if i have support for it?

```
glGenFramebuffers(1, &fbo);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fbo);

glGenTextures(1, &positionTexture);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, positionTexture);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB32F, width, height, 0, GL_RGB, GL_FLOAT, nullptr);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

    glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, positionTexture, 0);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`GL_RGB16F` and`GL_RGB32F` are *not* required color buffer formats in the GL, while `GL_RGBA32F` is. You can have a look in Table 8.12 of the [OpenGL 4.5 core profile specification](https://www.opengl.org/registry/doc/glspec45.core.pdf) (pages 198-200, assuming june 2017 revision of said document). It tells you that all these mentioned formats are *color renderable* but only `GL_RGBA32F` out of that set is a *required* render format. Implementations might support the other ones optionally, but you can't rely on that.

Comment: Your reference to Table 8.13 and corresponding page numbers seem off. Table 8.13 doesn't even mention `RGBA32F`. Did you mean 8.12 on pages 198—200?

Comment: @Ruslan: hmm, yes, thanks for the hint. According to appendix H.3 of the current 4.5 core spec, the document has ondergone 3 revisions after december 2015 when this answer was written... I still have a local copy of the August 2014 revision here, where the numbers are correct... Unfortunately, khronos just replaces the official spec documents with the newest revision, so that such de-syncs are very likely to happen... I think the gl specs are on a github repo now, so maybe it is better to link to a specific commit there...